# Qt's dialog box button size bug

Tags: c++, qt, qlayout

In a `QDialogButtonBox` class object, its button sizes are reduced:

[image]

While in other dialogs, the buttons look normal:

[image]

Both dialogs were made through Qt's Designer Mode, with no additional code on my part concerning these `QDialogButtonBox` class objects.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use layouts ?  If not you can see this tutorial to learn how to use it http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-layouts.html

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear; I want my buttons to be normal size, not so tiny like in the first image.

Comment: Please provide more details about the layout you have set and the QSizePolicy of the QDialogButtonBox.

Comment: show your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't post the code to show it, however, all the `QButtonDialogBox` options and properties, regarding the size policy and everything else, were not changed in code, thus having default values from Qt Designer.

The end result is that, in some dialogues, it looks well, and, in others, it simply doesn't... (As images in the previous post show.)

Removing/adding/changing the layouts hasn't changed anything...

I tend to think that something is wrong in the application, but I cannot figure out what.

I solved this problem by:

- Replacing `QMessageBox::question`call with `QMessageBox`object on stack.
- Setting minumum size for the buttons in the `QDialogButtonBox` object in the code.

I've been setting stylesheets just a couple of times in the code, but it has nothing to do with `QPushButton` or `QDialogButtonBox` objects... mainly changing background-colors for `QMenu` objects etc.

If I figure out what was the issue, I'll be sure to post it here!